# Android - how do I add context menu with about and quit choices?

Tags: android, eclipse, dialog, contextmenu

When using the Android Eclipse IDE, how do I add a menu that is triggered by the phone menu button such that it has to have an "About" choice that displays an "About my app" dialog and a "Quit" choice that exits the app?

Comment: hey sorry i guess it was a big question.  main thing was how do i get a menu to open and then open a dialog.  i could get the dialog to open directly ok b4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a content menu with about a quit items, please add all of the following to your project after first removing any other attempts at an about menu that might potentially conflict with this code.  Let Eclipse help you add the required imports or peruse the android documentation as you try to build this, and after everything's in place it should just work :-)

In /res create a folder menu containing a file main.xml with the following xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_quit"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_quit"/>
</menu>
```

In MainActivity.java add the following after your onCreate is closed:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
      AboutDialog about = new AboutDialog(this);
      about.setTitle(“About “my app);
      about.show();
      return true;
    case R.id.action_quit:
      System.exit(0);
      return true;
  }
}
```

Add a new java file but extend Dialog instead of Activity, like shown:

```
public class AboutDialog extends Dialog {
  public AboutDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_about);
  }
}
```

Finally, add a new layout dialog_about.xml like so:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</ScrollView>
```

Of course you’ll need to add another layout and content inside the ScrollView, and you may want other features in your menu and your quit item could use a confirmation (possibly).  But this should get you started.

Comment: You might have to create the folder, then create the new main.xml file within it.  I took the code from an existing project template I developed and use regularly so it was easy to find, I just added the quit section.

Comment: I think I see how this works but I get lots of errors.

Comment: sorry i see the part about imports so will try that.  im not advanced with android yet

Comment: Ah, ok.  It's complex at first.  Let me know if there are errors.  But if you click on each highlighted word in Eclipse, start from the top down within each java file, the first choice should be something like "Add Import Android.blah.whatever..." stuff.  Just click on those and see if the errors resolve themselves.  I didn't try to add those to my code for time but also since I don't know what you may already have imported in each file, and duplicate imports cause errors as well.

Comment: it works i mean the import thing is working but i have long way 2 go still thx i have 2 study this code more

Comment: Alright!  Your question was definitely rather all encompassing however so I only scratched the surface of some items.  Please ask more and I can help to walk you through the details to a certain extent, time permitting.